# Google Chart Calendar does not work november and december

Tags: charts, calendar

When I use the Google Chart API with Calendar package, it is not plotting the data when dates are on months November or December.

I am using the Google's code sample available on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar.

And, even using the google sample, if I change the month to November or December (index 10 or 11), the data is not ploted, but the other months are all ok.

Sample code from google:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["calendar"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
       var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
       dataTable.addRows([
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 13), 37032 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 14), 38024 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 15), 38024 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 16), 38108 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 3, 17), 38229 ],
          // Many rows omitted for brevity.
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 4), 38177 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 5), 38705 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 12), 38210 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 13), 38029 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 19), 38823 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 23), 38345 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 24), 38436 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 9, 30), 38447 ]
        ]);

       var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

       var options = {
         title: "Red Sox Attendance",
         height: 350,
       };

       chart.draw(dataTable, options);
   }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calendar_basic" style="width: 1000px; height: 350px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This still a bug in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is not that the months are not displaying due to size?
Taking the sample code above and changing the months to 10 (November) and 11 (December), it works fine.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/444vxz3n/) for the result. You might notice you have to scroll to see the last months. I suspect you had some limitation on your css that cut off the later months.

Code in the jsfiddle:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["calendar"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

   function drawChart() {
       var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
       dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Won/Loss' });
       dataTable.addRows([
          [ new Date(2012, 10, 13), 37032 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 10, 14), 38024 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 10, 15), 38024 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 11, 16), 38108 ],
          [ new Date(2012, 11, 17), 38229 ],
          // Many rows omitted for brevity.
          [ new Date(2013, 10, 4), 38177 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 10, 5), 38705 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 10, 12), 38210 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 10, 13), 38029 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 11, 19), 38823 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 11, 23), 38345 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 11, 24), 38436 ],
          [ new Date(2013, 11, 30), 38447 ]
        ]);

       var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar_basic'));

       var options = {
         title: "Red Sox Attendance",
         height: 350,
       };

       chart.draw(dataTable, options);
   }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calendar_basic" style="width: 1000px; height: 350px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The example doesn't not show it working. I second that. November and December isn't working for Google Calendar.

Comment: Does that mean you don't see them in the example jsfiddle? Please elaborate, I see dates marked for November and December.

Comment: Yes. I went in contact with Daniel from Google Vis and he is aware of this problem. It is related to timezone. I am in Brazil in GMT -3. He told me a fix will be around soon.

Comment: I see! That would explain why it works for me (I'm on a different timezone). Thanks :)